# Definition of a module over a Lie algebra

Tags: modules, lie-algebras

I have encountered the following definition on page 83 of *Structure and Geometry of Lie Groups*, by Hilgert & Neeb:

"Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra, and $V$ be a vector space. Suppose that $\mathfrak{g}\times V\rightarrow V,\;\;\;(x,v)\mapsto x\cdot v$ is a bilinear map. If $[x,y]\cdot v=x\cdot(y\cdot v)-y\cdot(x\cdot v)\;\;\;\text{ for }\;\;\;x,y\in\mathfrak{g},v\in V,$ then $V$ is called a *$\mathfrak{g}$-module*. "

In the same way that a vector space is defined as a triple $(V,+,\cdot)$, where '$\cdot$' is scalar multiplication, shouldn't a $\mathfrak{g}$-module be defined with respect to the map $(x,v)\mapsto x\cdot v$ as its 'scalar multiplication' map? In other words, shouldn't the definition end with "then $(V,+,\cdot)$ is called a *$\mathfrak{g}$-module*." Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're missing something. Have you ever encountered the term module before, particularly a module over a ring?

Comment: Yes, I have but I'm still fairly new to it.

Comment: The linear maps $V \to V$ could be thought of as a vector space using  the addition and composition of linear maps $V \to V$.  It can also be thought of as a Lie algebra using the addition and commutator of linear maps. The definition of $\mathfrak g$-module is saying that the effect of elements of $\mathfrak g$ on $V$ are by linear maps where the commutator of such linear maps behaves like the bracket in $\mathfrak g$ does as a linear map $V \to V$.  If your focus is on *notation* $(V,+,\cdot)$ instead of $V$, then you are right technically, but nobody does that.

Comment: Would you demand that a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ not be "just $V$" but has to be a tuple $(V,F,+_V,\cdot,+_F,\cdot_F)$ where $V$ is a set, $F$ is a set, and the other notation is the operations in $V$ and $F$ that are part of the definition of a vector space? Nobody goes around describing vector spaces over a field as such a $6$-tuple even if everyone knows it is technically correct. It is excessively pedantic most of the time. In the same way, everyone who knows what a topological space is will say "Let $X$ be a topological space" with the topology *understood* most of the time.

Comment: I wouldn't want to go over the top describing them as such, but I'm just trying to clarify my understanding before proceeding further. Is the definition above essentially equivalent to that of a Lie algebra representation?

Comment: I just read the 'formal definition' section here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_representation#Formal_definition and it seems to suggest that they are equivalent to each other, but they are defined separately in the book with no mention of equivalence...

Comment: Yes, these are basically the same thing except for the emphasis. A representation of $\mathfrak g$ on $V$ is a Lie algebra homomomorphism $\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak g\mathfrak l(V)$ rather than a mapping $\mathfrak g \times V \to V$ fitting some conditions. You could describe an action of the group $G$ on the set $X$ as a mapping $G \times X \to X$ fitting a few axioms or as a group homomorphism $G \to {\rm Aut}(X)$. At the end of the day they're the same concept from different points of view.

Comment: Thank you very much; I think I understand now.